# With what ratio does the Divide and Conquer Algorithm stop being O(N * log(N))

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

The divide and conquer algorithm has a runtime complexity of O(N * log(N)) because it splits the problem into 2 smaller subproblems. Then the algorithm can be run again on the two smaller problems recursively until you find the solution which gives you a runtime of O(N * log(N)). This is the strategy that some sorting algorithms use to achieve above mentioned runtime. (They split the problem into two equally sized parts -> ratio 1/2 and 1/2)

So what are the limits to the ratios of this division? Is the runtime still O(N*log(N)) if you split the problem into 1/4 and 3/4 original size? What about 1/10 and 9/10 or less?

Comment: [Master_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer it precisely based on the [Akra-Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method). If we have `T(n) = T(a*n) + T(b*n) + n` such that `a` and `b` are positive constant, less than 1, and `a + b = 1`, then we can say `T(n)` will be in `O(n log n)`.

Hence, for `a = 1/10` and `b = 9/10`, we can say the same as `a = 1/2` and `b = 1/2` or `a = 1/4` and `b = 3/4`.